# Configure Jenkins 2.0 with Ansible

Tags: jenkins, ansible, provisioning, jenkins-2

I am using Ansible for provision our servers, I installed the Jenkins 2.0 but it is becomeing with a startup configuration when I open the web UI. How can I do it with Ansible or shell or jenkins-cli. CentOS 7, Ansible 2.0.1.0. 
So,

1. Installing Jenkins 2.0 from http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat-rc/jenkins-2.0-1.1.noarch.rpm rpm.
2. Install java with yum.
3. Service start jenkins.
4. Open 192.168.46.10:8080, which is opening the Jenkins.
5. In Web UI adding the initial admin password.
6. In web UI select and install plugins.
7. In web UI create a new admin user.

The 5,6,7 points are all the startup config of the new Jenkins. I haven't idea how we can install it autmatically.

**Edit 1:**

The 1,2,3 point is already done, just I didn't share because it is not necessary, because I only need an advice how can I configure the Jenkins. But now I add it to my question.

```
---
- name: Jenkins - install | Install java
  yum: name=java state=installed

- name: Jenkins - install | Install Jenkins 2.0
  yum: pkg=http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat-rc/jenkins-2.0-1.1.noarch.rpm state=installed

- name: Jenkins - install | Start and enable Jenkins 2.0
  service: name=jenkins state=started enabled=yes
```

Comment: And what did you do so far? We are not going to do it for you.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul Nobody ask you to do it for me, because the 1,2,3 points are already done. I just don't know how can I manage the Jenkins configuration from cli. If you tell it to me it's enough for me, because I can use the shell module. I only used Jenkins from the Web UI which is not good when I want to install it automaticaly for a remote host.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I edited the question, now you can comment helpfully.

Comment: When you skip the wizard what do you do to install the basic plugins? Have you found a way to setup the tools (Jdk, Git, Maven) and credentials?

Comment: @MarkGargan I just did it manually, I copied them to the folder I think, but I don't remember.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution, this is turn off the setup wizard, after it I was able to change config files.

```
- name: Jenkins - configure | Turn off Jenkins setup wizard
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/sysconfig/jenkins regexp='^JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS=' line='JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false"'
  notify: restart jenkins
```

Comment: I'm seeing a similar problem, but this option `-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false` doesn't completely solve it. It does skip the setup wizard, but when I try to open the Jenkins UI or interact with it from `jenkins-cli.jar` it still asks for a username and password. Did you have this problem?

Comment: We have existed users and configs which we are copying to the Jenkins config folder, and it is solve the problem. @laffoyb

Comment: maybe this will help you @laffoyb https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security

Answer (score 8):

You can create an initialization script (in groovy) to add an admin account.
Script should be present in `$JENKINS_HOME/init.groovy.d/*.groovy`.
See [Jenkins CI Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=70877249) for more details.

Here's an example.

`security.groovy.j2` file:

```
#!groovy
import java.util.logging.Level
import java.util.logging.Logger
import hudson.security.*
import jenkins.model.*

def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
def logger = Logger.getLogger(Jenkins.class.getName())

logger.log(Level.INFO, "Ensuring that local user '{{ jenkins.admin_username }}' is created.")

if (!instance.isUseSecurity()) {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Creating local admin user '{{ jenkins.admin_username }}'.")

    def strategy = new FullControlOnceLoggedInAuthorizationStrategy()
    strategy.setAllowAnonymousRead(false)

    def hudsonRealm = new HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm(false)
    hudsonRealm.createAccount("{{ jenkins.admin_username }}", "{{ jenkins.admin_password }}")

    instance.setSecurityRealm(hudsonRealm)
    instance.setAuthorizationStrategy(strategy)
    instance.save()
}
```

How to use in Ansible playbook:

```
- name: Create initialization scripts directory
  file: path={{ jenkins.home }}/init.groovy.d
        state=directory
        owner=jenkins
        group=jenkins
        mode=0775

- name: Add initialization script to setup basic security
  template: src=security.groovy.j2
            dest={{ jenkins.home }}/init.groovy.d/security.groovy
```

I was inspired by this [GitHub](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-jenkins/blob/master/templates/basic-security.groovy) reposiotry.

Comment: The GitHub link returns 404 now. The closest I could find is https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-jenkins/blob/master/templates/basic-security.groovy.j2

Answer (score 2):

The above solution didn't work for me but give me hint and this is the solution that worked for me on Ubuntu:

```
- name: Configure JVM Arguments
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/default/jenkins
    regexp: '^JAVA_ARGS='
    line: 'JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false"'
  notify:
    - Restart Jenkins
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that `/etc/default/jenkins` is for Debian/Ubuntu variants whereas `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` is for CentOS/RedHat variants.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 16.04 with [Jenkins installed using apt-get](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu), this works:

```
- name: "Turn off Jenkins setup wizard"
  lineinfile:
      dest: /etc/init.d/jenkins
      regexp: '^JAVA_ARGS='
      line: 'JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false"'
      insertbefore: '^DAEMON_ARGS='
  notify: restart jenkins

- name: restart jenkins
  service: name=jenkins state=restarted
```

You will still have to setup the security though!