# Scripting through Jenkins initial password

Tags: powershell, jenkins, chef-infra, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to set up a Chef recipe to install and manage a Jenkins server. So far I can get the server installed and manage it's config so that it listens on port 80.

My problem right now is that I can't get it to scripts it's way through the initial administrator password so I can actually access the server.

So far I have the script blow that can find the password and submit the web page back to Jenkins, but Jenkins always claims the password is incorrect.

Is there any easier way to get this done than scraping Jenkins' web pages? Maybe a way to avoid this password screen after install entirely?

Thanks,

Bill

```
$hostName = $env:computername

    if(-not (Test-Path 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword'))
    {
        exit -1
    } else {
        $password = Get-Content 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword'
    }

    $loginPage = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://$hostName/login?from%2f" -UseBasicParsing -SessionVariable session

    $xmlPage = ([xml]$loginPage.Content)

    $xmlPage.SelectNodes('//input[@name = "j_password"]').setAttribute('value',$password)

    $actionPath = $xmlPage.SelectNodes('//form').action

    $responsePage = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://$hostName/$actionPath" -UseBasicParsing -WebSession $session -Body ($xmlPage.SelectNodes('//input').OuterXML) -Method Post
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file `${JENKINS_HOME}/jenkins.install.InstallUtil.lastExecVersion` and set content to `2.0` **without any line terminators**.
Also, you can launch Jenkins with the following key `-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false` to avoid initial setup wizard.

[How to "Unlock Jenkins"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35960883/how-to-unlock-jenkins) or [Configure Jenkins 2.0 with Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604504/configure-jenkins-2-0-with-ansible)

Also, take a look here, it seems that the flag got modified a bit: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jenkinsci-users/Pb4QZVc2-f0/ywKqZVf9MgAJ

Comment: Testing now. Thanks very much! I'll mark this solution as the answer as soon as my Chef Recipe runs and the screen is gone.